# Do I still need to use traditional way to implement Preferences Settings Screen in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

At present I use Jetpack Compose in my Android Studio project.

I find many [projects](https://blog.mindorks.com/implementing-preferences-settings-screen-in-android) still to use traditional way to implement a Preferences Settings Screen after I Google it.

I hope to implement a Preferences Settings Screen when I use Jetpack Compose, I don't know if there is a new way to implement Preferences Settings Screen, could you tell me?

And more,  from the official [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings), it still need to use XML resource and `PreferenceFragmentCompat` to create Preference screen. It seems that I havn't found a sample project to create Preference screen with Jetpack Compose or other way.

But, from the [document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#groovy), it seems that `SharedPreferences` will be obsoleted.

Comment: You could star this issue to add your vote and track progress: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199606757

Comment: Do you need more help on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just leaving my opinion here...

I work for a consulting company, and in my last 12 years working with Android I didn't use this API at all, just because clients usually want a UI with a better design than that provided by Preferences UI API. Also, I think the approach provided by this API violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) since it mixes UI and Storage in the same component.

Finally, create a settings screens is a very simple task since they usually uses simple components like `CheckBox`, `Switch`, `TextField`, `Slider`, ...
Therefore, I hadn't use and wouldn't plan to use the Preferences UI API.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a sample code to set Preferences with Jetpack Compose?

Comment: I did that in my sample project: https://github.com/nglauber/books_compose it's in settings module

Comment: Thanks! But your sample project is huge, and I can't run, and I can't find settings module